# Variance of EWMA (Exponentially Weighted Moving Average)

Tags: statistics, variance

It is assumed that the quality characteristic of interest, denoted by $Y_i$, follows a Normal distribution with mean $μ$ and variance $σ^2$.

We take a sample of size $n$ at time $t$ and measure its quality characteristic. 
The EWMA statistic at time $t$, denoted by $M_t$, is
\begin{align}
 (Eq.1):   M_t = (1-λ)M_{t-1} + λ\bar{Y_t} + k(\bar{Y_t}-\bar{Y_{t-1}})
\end{align} (Eq.1)

where $\bar{Y_t}$ is the sample mean at time t and k is a constant.

**Attempt**
\begin{gather*}
   E[M_t] = (1-λ)E[M_{t-1}] + λE[\bar{Y_t}] + k(E[\bar{Y_t}]] - E [\bar{Y_{t-1}}])
\end{gather*} 
**Q1**: I now assume $E[M_t] = E[M_{t-1}]$, is this correct?

Therefore,

\begin{gather*}
   E[M_t] = \frac{1}{λ}λμ + k(μ-μ) = μ
\end{gather*}

And for the variance,

\begin{gather*}
   V[M_t] = (1-λ)^2V[M_{t-1}] + λ^2V[\bar{Y_t}] + k^2(V[\bar{Y_t}] + V[\bar{Y_{t-1}}]) + 2(1-λ)(λCov(M_{t-1},\bar{Y_t}) + k( Cov(M_{t-1},\bar{Y_t}) - Cov(M_{t-1},\bar{Y_{t-1}}) ))
\end{gather*}
**Q2**: Above, I asumed $\bar{Y_t}$ and $\bar{Y_{t-1}}$ are independent, since $Y_{i,t}$ are independent.

**Q3**: Is $M_{t-1}$ independent from $\bar{Y_t}$ and $\bar{Y_{t-1}}$?

For my third question, my answer would be that $M_{t-1}$ is dependent on the sample means since there is a relation between them (Eq.1). I don't know if this is trivial but I wanted to make sure I am not missing something here.

Thank you.

Comment: Update:

https://ibb.co/yYHRpDq

I have tried a different approach and reached this result.

1)The third term (sum) of the variance is due to the covariances of the two sums of M_t.

2)I didn't know how to calculate the sums of the variance, so I searched through some scientific papers and found that. I figured out what the result would be but not how you actually reach that. Does anyone know?